# When will Landscape be available for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: server, landscape

I wanted to install Landscape on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, just to found out it isn't supported yet.

I looked around on the www but didn't find an ETA. Only a reference that it should be released in a few weeks (posted 17 April): https://askubuntu.com/a/758418/67290.

Who can give me an ETA or knows a mailinglist where I can sign up to let me know when a new version of Landscape is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I noticed that Landscape is available for 16.04 LTS, making my question obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

It will show up on the frontpage of https://help.landscape.canonical.com when xenial support is ready.

Answer (score 1):

It is ready now, the delay was unfortunate but has lead to a better, less buggy, release. Please go ahead and use Landscape 16.06 with Ubuntu 16.04 support.