# Can't install Ubuntu Landscape on Raspberry Pi

Tags: apt, software-installation, landscape

I'm trying to install Landscape on my Ubuntu Mate server to manage it.
I have added the repository with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/17.03
```

This didn't give any errors. After that I updated my package list using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

No errors. But then if I install Landscape using:

```
sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart
```

It says

```
Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart
```

I'm using Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi 3b.

Answer (score 2):

[It would appear that in that PPA there are only packages for landscape server for i386 and amd64 architectures](https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/17.03/+packages), meaning at this time I don't think it's supported to run landscape server on a raspberry pi. The landscape client will run on the pi if you wish to manage the pi using landscape, but you won't be able to use it to host that particular server.

The reason it's coming up not found is either because that package (the server) isn't available for your current platform or for your current version of Ubuntu (it's [only supported on 14.04 Trusty or 16.04 Xenial](https://askubuntu.com/a/758418/103537) - LTS releases.)

If you want to run Landscape Server on premises, I'm afraid that at this time you will need an i386 or x64 system running one of those LTS releases in order to try it out.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there other software to manage my  Rpi server?

Comment: Well, let me clarify: You can run Landscape *client* on your raspberry pi to manage it, but you would need a separate i386 or x64 computer running somewhere else on your network to serve as the server. Computers managed by Landscape need the client software.